# Rails 3 default exception+404 handling for JSON requests

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, http-status-code-404

By default Rails serves a helpful HTML page for `404 Resource Not Found` and `500 Internal Server Error`. But for my JSON API I'd like to serve JSON-formatted replies.

How can I set up default exception-handling for JSON requests?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a base controller for all API controllers:

```
NOT_FOUND_EXC = [ActionController::RoutingError,
                 AbstractController::ActionNotFound,
                 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound]

class BaseapiController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json
  rescue_from StandardError, with: :show_json_error

  def resource_not_found
    url = request.fullpath
    respond_with(url), status: :not_found)
  end

  private

  def show_json_errors(exc)
    case exc
      when *NOT_FOUND_EXC
        return resource_not_found
      else
        logger.error exc.message
        logger.error exc.backtrace.join("\n")
        respond_with(exc), status: :internal_server_error)
    end
  end
end
```

And I've defined this in `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :api do
  ...
end
match 'api/*url', to: 'baseapi#resource_not_found'
```

Now the `rescue_from` clause captures all exceptions and unmatched routes are captured via `#resource_not_found`.

I think this misses some fundamentals on Rails exception handling though, because usually errors should be handled with expressive details in development and render simply in prod. I'm obviously not doing that here. And HTML exceptions can still leak through. So feedback and alternatives welcome, I'm new to Rails and hope I'm missing a mechanism to hook into.